# Как изменить встроенные сообщения об ошибках в собственном обработчике ошибок?

Tags: php

Вот такие например:

```
str_ireplace() expects at least 3 parameters, 0 given
Undefined variable: var
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.set-error-handler.php

Answer (score 0):

Простой пример:

```
// Перехват ошибок и предупреждений.
set_error_handler(function ($errno, $msg) {
    echo 'Ошибка № <b>'. $errno .'</b><br />'. 
        'Текст ошибки: <b>'. $msg .'</b>';
}, E_ALL);

// Сгенерируем ошибку (деление на ноль)
$i = 0;
$j = 1;

$j / $i;
```

Comment: Я имею ввиду само сообщение ошибки, то есть в случае не существующей переменной : Undefined variable: var и это сообщение заменить например на: Переменная var не определена.